# How to write a file for app but not used by user?

Tags: android

I want to create a file t save some information for my app next time initial use.
I want the file is place in program not in sd card.
What position of the file I can set?

```
InputStreamReader fsr = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(**what position** +"test.xml"));
```

Comment: Why dont you use shared preference?

Comment: Using SharedPreferences is a better way from reading off a file. Saves a lot of trouble

Comment: It seems useful for me!! Thanks a lot

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 - It depends what OP wants to store and read. Using shared preferences for storing a large XML document is awkward at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context.getDir() also return private directory of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Use [openFileInput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29)/[openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), which can be called for any Context (including your Activity).